# Wi-Fi connection getting lost after some time (Linux)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, internet, fedora

I have a laptop (HP ProBook 455 G9) that I connect to a Wi-Fi. I use Fedora 39 with GNOME, NetworkManager and kernel 6.7.7-200.fc39.x86_64. The Wi-Fi chip is RealRek RTL8852BE. I don't think I have done any non-standard configuration (I only tried manipulation with Wi-Fi power saving but that was only one of my tries to fix this problem).

**After some time after boot (sometimes few minutes, sometimes hours, sometimes never), the system looses the Wi-Fi connection and can't connect to any Wi-Fi.** The Wi-Fi icon disappears, when clicking "All Networks", only the progress bar/circle is displayed. The problem happens with every Wi-Fi I have tried.

Turning Wi-Fi on/off doesn't help. Killing wpa_supplicant and restarting NetworkManager doesn't help. The only thing that helps is a PC restart.

I was checking NetworkManager logs and found this:

```
Mar 04 08:22:10 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536930.8059] manager: (lo): new Loopback device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Mar 04 08:22:10 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536930.8062] device (lo): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 04 08:22:10 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536930.8064] device (lo): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 04 08:22:10 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536930.8068] device (lo): Activation: starting connection 'lo' (4aa838cb-a2b0-4b9b-a6c0-22aaafe7bb8e)
Mar 04 08:22:10 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536930.8073] manager: (enp1s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Mar 04 08:22:10 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536930.8074] device (enp1s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 04 08:22:10 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536930.8082] device (wlp2s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Mar 04 08:22:10 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536930.8086] manager: (wlp2s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Mar 04 08:22:10 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536930.8087] device (wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 04 08:22:10 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <warn>  [1709536930.9509] platform-linux: do-change-link[3]: failure 110 (Connection timed out)
Mar 04 08:22:10 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536930.9511] device (wlp2s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 32:2D:88:52:50:FD (scanning)
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <warn>  [1709536931.0929] platform-linux: do-change-link[3]: failure 110 (Connection timed out)
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536931.0940] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536931.1000] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536931.1024] device (lo): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536931.1026] device (lo): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536931.1028] device (lo): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536931.1034] device (lo): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536931.1049] device (lo): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536931.1050] device (lo): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536931.1053] device (lo): Activation: successful, device activated.
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <error> [1709536931.3851] device (wlp2s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Mar 04 08:22:11 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536931.7962] agent-manager: agent[bcdddf15828c5142,:1.86/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Mar 04 08:22:16 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536936.8117] manager: startup complete
Mar 04 08:22:21 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <warn>  [1709536941.8174] device (wlp2s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#1).
Mar 04 08:22:22 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <error> [1709536942.1022] device (wlp2s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Mar 04 08:22:32 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <warn>  [1709536952.8196] device (wlp2s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#2).
Mar 04 08:22:33 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <error> [1709536953.1055] device (wlp2s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Mar 04 08:22:43 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <warn>  [1709536963.8148] device (wlp2s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#3).
Mar 04 08:22:44 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <error> [1709536964.1002] device (wlp2s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Mar 04 08:22:54 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <warn>  [1709536974.8231] device (wlp2s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#4).
Mar 04 08:22:55 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <error> [1709536975.1082] device (wlp2s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Mar 04 08:23:05 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <warn>  [1709536985.8151] device (wlp2s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#5).
Mar 04 08:23:06 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <error> [1709536986.1002] device (wlp2s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Mar 04 08:23:06 martin NetworkManager[10448]: <info>  [1709536986.1002] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface keeps failing, giving up
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your model is being shipped with a Realtek chip or a Qualcomm one. Which one is yours? If the latter it should just work with the kernel you're using. If the former you may want to try this: https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RTW89_8852BE.html

Comment: `lspci` says: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller. `cat /boot/config-6.7.7-200.fc39.x86_64  | grep RTW89_8852BE` says the config has value "m". I am not sure what should I do with that.

Comment: 1. Please [edit] and add that info to the question, it's actually much more relevant than the log. 2. You may try the alternative drivers as discussed here: https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/how-to-install-the-driver-for-wifi-chip-rtl8852be/68307

Comment: Also discussed here some options (not really a reliable source but...): https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/18l584v/need_help_identifying_wifi_stability_issue/ And indeed you may need to update UEFI ("BIOS") for optimal performance.